# Do I need to delete OpenGL shader objects even if compilation fails?

Tags: c++, opengl

When shader compilation fails, do I need to delete the shaders? And is the failed shader included to this process too?

Like this:

```
for(size_t Size = 0; Size < this->Shaders.size(); Size++) //"Shaders" is a vector.
{       
    glDeleteShader(this->Shaders[Size]);
}
```

Comment: `Size <= this->Shaders.size()`  If `Shaders` is indeed a vector, this is an out-of-bounds access on the last iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you do have to delete them. According to the [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glCreateShader.xhtml), `glCreateShader` creates an empty shader object. So even if subsequent attempts to attach shader source (`glShaderSource`) and/or compilation of said source (`glCompileShader`) fail, you still allocated a shader object that needs to be destroyed by a call to `glDestroyShader`.

---

TL;DR: Always destroy shader objects that you created, even if compilation failed.